# Schedule a local notification that would work even if the RN app is killed

Tags: react-native, notifications

I'm currently looking for a way to send scheduled local notifications for iOS/Android.

So far, posts I've seen tell me that when the app is killed, RN code won't execute. I understand that.

Could somebody explain me like I'm 5, how could I implement that feature and if I need to go through native code, what are the steps?

Thanks :)

Comment: [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#scheduled-notifications) Look under Scheduled Notification, which is under Usage